# Is it possible to integrate AutoFill Linkedin into elementor forms?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I need to insert automatic filling of the fields of my forms via Linkedin.
I set up Linkedin, everything is OK.
I have integrated in my "footer" the code provided by Linkedin:

I set up the parameters according to the indications"Using the code example below, replace the sample entries with the corresponding entries from your own source code. For example, replace "12345" in the code below with the "id" value from the corresponding field in your  element."

If you want to see my form page:
https://www.infrastructure-services.fr/deposer-mon-cv-sans-connexion/

Please let me know if this is possible? Or if I made a mistake?
A great day

Comment: Is your domain whitelisted on Linkedin ? You say you setup the parameters to map your form entries, I don't see it in you source code. I don't see any autofill button either on your form (which triggers the autofill). Did you check [the demo form on Linkedin](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/cx/17/02/the-sophisticated-marketers-guide-to-linkedin) ? Last but not least, your page is triggering a 400 error (bad request) on the GET `Request URL: https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/`

Comment: Hello and thank you for taking the time to look.
It seems to me that my domain is on a white list.
I have integrated the insight tag on all the pages of my site.
Then I followed the information provided by linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/65688/linkedin-autofill-setup-guide?lang=en

Comment: This url forms https://www.infrastructure-services.fr/deposer-mon-cv-sans-connexion/